# Button to dismiss posting guidance for anonymous answer authors is misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, anonymous-visitors

[image]

I took that screenshot while I was signed out, trying to post as an anonymous author on Physics SE. That banner automatically slides up and it suggests some general guidelines for posting. 
The "ok" button to dismiss that banner is kind of hovering about somewhere in the middle of things. Can it be shifted to the left a bit, such that it's completely on top of the yellow banner? It would be great if we could make it a bit more conspicuous too...

I'm on Vivaldi 2.0 for Windows 10, but it shows up on Chrome for Windows 10 too.